# How to remove whitespace via php preg_replace between all brackets in text

Tags: php, regex

I have the The similar text:

> "Eat [ 12 ] my [ 15]  shorts [ 20 ]"

And I would like to remove whitespace from all brackets in string.

I tried something like:

```
$str = 'Eat [ 12 ] my [ 15]  shorts [ 20 ]';
$str = preg_replace_callback("~\([^\)]*)\)~", function($s) {
    return str_replace(" ", "", "($s[1])");
}, $str);
echo $str;
```

But still without succes.

Could somebody tell my, how to do this right way please?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Eat [ 12 ] my [ 15]  shorts [ 20 ]';
$str = preg_replace('#\[\s+#', '[', $str);
$str = preg_replace('#\s+\]#', ']', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that there is going to be only **one** white space, you can use simple str_replace. That will be a lot faster then preg_replace:

```
$str = str_replace( array( '[ ', ' ]' ), array( '[', ']' ), $str );
```